# Specifying external font in JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, fonts, javafx

Is it possible to specify a font using CSS in JavaFX application? I have an FXML scene and the corresponding CSS file. In Java code, it's possible to specify a font using the `setFont` method:

```
text.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:resources/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf", 12));
```

I tried different constructions, like:

```css
-fx-font-family: url("../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf");
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were close to the solution:

```css
-fx-font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Try this, it should work fine.

---

Maybe this could help? (I'm not an expert in JavaFX)

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10107625

---

**EDIT**:

Load your font:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Delicious;
    src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf');
}
```

Use your font with `-fx-`:

```css
-fx-font-family: 'Delicious';
```

Comment: My question about external font, because I need to use my font, instead of using already installed on user system.

Comment: same way. use `@Font-face` to load font and then in `-fx-font-family` you put the name of your font.

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, according to [this JavaFX tracking issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-10343), @font-face support isn't scheduled to be added to JavaFX until JavaFX 8/JDK 8 timeframe.

Comment: @AndreaTurri doesn't seem to work for me - tested in the latest v. of JavaFX Scene Builder. How did you test this?

Comment: @AndreaTurri it does *not* work in JavaFX 2.2! See the [JavaFX Jira issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-10343) referenced by jewelsea for details. It was clarified that this is a JavaFX 8 feature only and there are no plans to backport to 2.2. See [jewelseas other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12181948/1717169) for a proper way to load custom fonts in JavaFX 2.2 which actually works.

Comment: Remember to declare your `@font-face` first in the CSS for it to work!

Answer (score 22):

I use a combination of application code and CSS to style via an external font.

I place the `loadFont` call inside an overridden Application init method to make sure it is invoked before anything much happened in the application.

```
Font.loadFont(CustomFontTest.class.getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(), 10);
```

To use the font, I reference the font by font family in CSS:

```css
.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-family: TRON;
    -fx-font-size: 40px;
}

.context-menu {
    -fx-font-family: TRON;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
```

Nice that the CSS sizes the fonts fine.
Even when the font is loaded at size 10, the font was resized correctly to what is specified in the CSS `-fx-font-size` specifications.

Inline styling of a label via CSS using a `Font` loaded during application initialization also works fine:

```
Label testControl = new Label("TRON");
testControl.setStyle("-fx-font-family: TRON; -fx-font-size: 120;");
```

The [TRON font](http://www.dafont.com/tron.font) was downloaded from dafont and placed in the same directory as the CustomFontTest class and copied to the build output directory by the build system.

Answer copied from my answer to a forum post on ["Using Custom Fonts"](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10210565).

Comment: I've gotten it to work with `Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("TRON.TTF"), 10);` instead. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just found out one more detail:
In JavaFX-8 if you want to have regular and bold variants of the same font you can specify them with two instances of @font-face. Then you can use -fx-font-weight: bold;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans';
    src: url('DroidSans.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Bold';
    src: url('DroidSans-Bold.ttf');
}

.root {
    -fx-font-family: 'Droid Sans'; 
}

.table-row-cell:focused .text {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to load font using FileIUnputStream, thus you don't need to use css:

```
 @FXML
    private Label myLabel;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){

Font myFont = null;

        try {
            myFont = Font.loadFont(new FileInputStream(new File("patch_to_font.ttf")), 10);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myLabel.setFont(myFont);

}
```

Comment: The original question is about how to use this loaded fonr in CSS. Sure, you can load font file directly, but how you would like to use it in forms stylesheets?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I had problems with using custom font in CSS, so this was my alternative solution. Anyway you're right - it's not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaFx CSS fonts (import .ttf):**

```
/* import fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans Light";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans ExtraBold";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf");
}

/* Set fonts */

.settings-name{
    -fx-font-size: 33px;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans Light";
    -fx-font-weight: 300;
    -fx-text-fill: #09f;
}

.settings-username{
    -fx-font-size: 19px;
    -fx-font-family: "Open Sans ExtraBold";
    -fx-font-weight: 900;
    -fx-text-fill: #09f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `Font.ttf` file in our `bin/<main application> folder`, that contains the `.class` of your application [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv11s.png)