# Can't set custom font

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, javafx-css

I'm working on a JavaFX project. I'd like to use custom font on a `Label` from a CSS file. I've read and followd eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181948/2625561) post.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        Font font = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Dimitri_Swank.ttf"), 32);
        System.out.println(font);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Window.fxml"));
        // ...
    }
}
```

It prints `Font[name=Dimitri Swank, family=Dimitri Swank, style=Regular, size=32.0]`, so that the font is loaded successfully. The root container in the FXML file has a `stylesheets="@Window.css"` attribute, and in this CSS file, there is a rule:

```
#gameName {
    -fx-font-family: Dimitri Swank;
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
}
```

The selector works well (it refers to a `Label`), I can see the difference if I change the `-fx-font-size`. But the font family remains the default system font. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your linked post's answer, I saw that they had their `-fx-font-family` in quotes, did you try doing `-fx-font-family:'Dimitri Swank';`?

Comment: @MichaelPickett lol that's so easy, and it solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from `JavaFX version 1.8u60` you can use plain css to load the font but with carefull that you need to use the exactly original name of the `Font File`,for example:

```
@font-face{
    src: url("../fonts/Younger than me Bold.ttf");
}

.button{
  -fx-background-color:white;
  -fx-background-radius:15.0;
  -fx-font-size:18.0;
  -fx-font-family:"Younger than me";
  -fx-text-fill:black;
  -fx-font-weight:bold;  
}
```

Mention that the original name can be found opening the `.ttf` with a default editor and see it's name in case if you don't know it.

Complete tutorial:http://www.guigarage.com/2014/10/integrate-custom-fonts-javafx-application-using-css/

Have a look also here for your situation:[Specifying external font in JavaFX CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css#12181948)

---

**Finally:**

The problem in your code is that in the css you are not adding double quotes `"` or single quotes `'` around the `font - family`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this way tomorrow.