# How to load cutom fonts on java fx

Tags: java, javafx

I've been working on a Java fx program and wanted to add Amharic characters to a text area. i tried to add custom fonts using CSS but it doesn't seem to be working and i end up with square boxes instead of the characters. I'm trying to render Amharic characters and  here's the CSS code.

```
@font-face {
    src: url('AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf');
}

.text {
    -fx-font-family: 'Abyssinica SIL';
}
```

also if anyone knows how to add the fonts in the controller class or the FXML file it'd help a lot. thankyou in advance.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css You have to set the font family in the @font-face block.

Comment: OMG thank you so much you have saved me 5hrs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying external font in JavaFX CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css)