# Why is the text when I run the program not the same as when I see it in scene builder? -- Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, encoding, fonts, scenebuilder

I am trying to use a font that I downloaded and it works fine when I use it in the scene builder the text is written correctly

[image: scene builder text]

But when I run it in intellij it does not have the same output.

[image: idea]

this is the fxml code that was written by scene builder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="145.0" minWidth="706.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Muslim_Qibla.Controllers.Mushaf">
   <children>
      <Line fx:id="l" endX="580.0" layoutX="440.0" layoutY="219.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeWidth="2.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="419.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="218.0" />
      <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="441.0" layoutY="252.0" prefHeight="613.0" prefWidth="582.0" stylesheets="@../Css_Files/c.css" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" vmax="100.0">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
      <Rectangle fx:id="ddd" arcHeight="25.0" arcWidth="25.0" fill="#080927" height="800.0" layoutX="384.0" layoutY="104.0" opacity="0.9" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="680.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="376.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="104.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="co" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#232323" opacity="0.5" pickOnBounds="true" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="1024.0" fitWidth="1440.0" opacity="0.96" pickOnBounds="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Files/Mus'haf.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="WHITE" height="40.0" layoutX="219.1999969482422" layoutY="70.4000015258789" pickOnBounds="true" stroke="#dfdbe1" strokeType="INSIDE" width="450.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="219.1999969482422" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.4000015258789" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" layoutX="683.2000122070312" layoutY="80.4000015258789" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="633.2000122070312" AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.4000015258789">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Files/search.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" layoutX="259.20001220703125" layoutY="50.400001525878906" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="416.0" promptText="ابحث" stylesheets="@../Css_Files/f.css" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="209.20001220703125" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.400001525878906">
         <font>
            <Font name="kfgqpc_hafs_uthmanic_script Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#7e2092" height="40.0" layoutX="532.0" layoutY="126.4000015258789" opacity="0.8" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="532.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="126.4000015258789" />
      <Text fx:id="surah" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="599.1599731445312" layoutY="146.39999389648438" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="الكهف" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="601.3199732303619" AnchorPane.topAnchor="138.65999364852905">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="surah2" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="737.0" layoutY="146.39999389648438" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="سورة" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="737.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="138.4">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal-Medium" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="m1" layoutX="532.0" layoutY="126.4000015258789" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying2" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="179.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="532.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="126.4000015258789" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#7e2092" height="40.0" layoutX="219.1999969482422" layoutY="126.4000015258789" opacity="0.8" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="219.1999969482422" AnchorPane.topAnchor="126.4000015258789" />
      <Text fx:id="surah1" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="249.1999969482422" layoutY="146.39999389648438" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="الخامس عشر" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="246.96799683570862" AnchorPane.topAnchor="135.64799404144287">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="surah21" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="425.0" layoutY="136.0" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="الجزء" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="425.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="136.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal-Medium" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="m" layoutX="219.1999969482422" layoutY="126.4000015258789" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="179.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="219.1999969482422" AnchorPane.topAnchor="126.4000015258789" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="hhh" arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#f3f3f3" height="761.0" layoutX="219.0" layoutY="187.0" opacity="0.9" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="951.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="75.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="219.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="269.79999999999995" AnchorPane.topAnchor="187.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="8.0" arcWidth="8.0" fill="#d1a476" height="100.0" layoutX="1069.0" layoutY="175.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" width="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="331.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="175.0" />
      <Polygon fill="#e0dbe3" layoutX="1088.800048828125" layoutY="272.20001220703125" points="-20.5999755859375, 4.79998779296875, 20.4000244140625, 4.79998779296875, 0.0, -20.20001220703125" stroke="#e0dbe3" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="330.7999267578125" AnchorPane.topAnchor="252.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#7e2092" height="40.0" layoutX="1195.0" layoutY="186.0" opacity="0.8" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="45.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="186.0" />
      <Text fx:id="surah22" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="1240.719970703125" layoutY="206.0" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="حفظ علامة" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="90.89602780342102" AnchorPane.topAnchor="198.23600006103516">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="m11" layoutX="1195.0" layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="179.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="65.80000000000001" AnchorPane.topAnchor="186.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#7e2092" height="40.0" layoutX="1195.199951171875" layoutY="247.1999969482422" opacity="0.8" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="44.800048828125" AnchorPane.topAnchor="247.1999969482422" />
      <Text fx:id="surah221" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="1262.3599853515625" layoutY="267.20001220703125" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="علامات" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="108.44801688194275" AnchorPane.topAnchor="259.4600119590759">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="m111" layoutX="1195.199951171875" layoutY="252.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="179.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="252.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="30.0" arcWidth="30.0" fill="#7e2092" height="50.0" layoutX="640.7999877929688" layoutY="956.0" opacity="0.8" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="158.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="18.0" />
      <Text fx:id="surah2211" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="696.1437377929688" layoutY="981.0" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="۳۰۲" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="31.796875">
         <font>
            <Font name="Tajawal" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="m1111" layoutX="645.7999877929688" layoutY="960.1937255859375" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="147.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.606274414062497" />
      <Text fx:id="surah23" boundsType="VISUAL" fill="WHITE" layoutX="1028.0" layoutY="40.0" smooth="false" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="القرآن الكريم" textAlignment="CENTER" textOrigin="TOP" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="143.40625" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="kfgqpc_hafs_uthmanic_script Regular" size="64.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <ImageView fitHeight="64.0" fitWidth="64.0" layoutX="1334.25" layoutY="46.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="41.75" AnchorPane.topAnchor="46.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Files/menu.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="m2" layoutX="1332.25" layoutY="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#trying" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="67.0" textFill="#7e2092" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.55" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I updated scene builder to version 21 and then updated java and javafx version to the latest one and even changed it to openjdk version 21 and javafx version 21, so it can be the same as the one in scnene builder and I tried to look if the encoding is correct but I didn't find anything that was wrong

and I am running it on windows 11
and this the font I am using https://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp02/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/UthmanicHafs1_Ver13.zip
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Tajawal

Comment: Offtopic: "I" is always capitalized.  Tools such as [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com) can help you fix such issues.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mcve].  Your question should include everything needed to reproduce the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition.  Just code that displays some text in a stage is fine, not an entire replica of your project scene.  A link to obtain the font for testing should be provided.  Update your question to include version information for OS, JDK, JavaFX and SceneBuilder.

Comment: "_font that i downloaded_" -- How did you add the font?

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the input I tried to add as much information as possible to make my question clear and changed all the 'i' to 'I' and thanks for making the pictures inline pictures since this my first time posting a question here

Comment: @Slaw I downloaded the font from a site the link that I just added to the post and then installed it for all users

Comment: Just to clarify, you installed the font to the OS instead of loading it in JavaFX, right? Also, the problem is specifically with the button at the bottom of the scene, yes? Everything else looks like it's displaying the same between the two images.

Comment: @Slaw yes I installed the font to the OS also not only the button at the bottom, but also the text at the upper right corner of the screen there is a letter that is not written. Moreover, I intend to add more text that use more special characters, but since the basic text didn't work I didn't add it yet

Comment: It looks like the bottom center button is not using the font at all in SceneBuilder.  That explains the discrepancy between the images.  But I’m not sure why the font works in one place, but not in another.

Comment: Not  sure if this is the problem, but when I load the two `*.ttf` files from the provided ZIP file directly in JavaFX I get two fonts: One named `KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script Regular` and the other named `KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script Bold`. Neither of those names match what you have in the FXML file; are you sure the fonts are even being applied?

Comment: @VGR no the buttom center button uses the font in scene builder and you can see it in the fxml code

Comment: @Slaw yes my fonts are being applied but I am using more than one font and I forgot to add the second one, but I am using the font only in those 2 texts and all of the left text are the other font and I added it to the post

Comment: The names you use for the *Tajawal* family match what JavaFX reports when loading the fonts. But you still seem to be using the wrong names for the *KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script* family. Also, I cannot reproduce this using JavaFX 21.0.2 with Java 21.0.1 on Windows 11. I've installed the fonts to the OS, and they display in both *Scene Builder* and a test JavaFX application. Though for the test application, when I loaded the fonts manually (before installing them), `۳۰۲` was displayed as three rectangles. I don't know why; regardless, manually loading the fonts doesn't match your scenario.

Comment: As an aside, note that `Font` is not guaranteed to give you the exact font you requested. In the worst case, it seems to fall back to the default font if it can't find the specified font at all. This behavior can make it difficult to realize something went wrong. That's why I asked if you were *sure* the correct font was being set on your text objects. What do you see when you query their `font` property at run-time?

Comment: @Slaw I tried to print the font name during runtime and it printed the exact font that I wanted it to use, but I don't know if this is what you meant or is there any other way to check it?

Comment: That's what I meant (e.g., `System.out.println(textObj.getFont())`). If the correct fonts are being found and applied, then I honestly don't know what's wrong. Perhaps you've encountered a bug in JavaFX.

Comment: @Slaw this is exactly what I wrote I think maybe the problem is with encoding, but I don't know how to check it

Comment: See if you can substitute a different font, also capable of displaying the characters you need, for the broken one.  Does that display correctly or not?

Comment: JavaFX can source fonts that are not installed in your OS, if you want to try that.  You can [load fonts from resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm), or use [web fonts](http://fxexperience.com/2012/12/use-webgoogle-fonts-in-javafx/).  Instructions to [load from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css/12181948#12181948).

Comment: @jewelsea I have done what you have said and yes they were displayed correctly, but I don't understand why they were not displayed correctly by the previous font?

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the help I think that this was a glitch or a bug in scene builder because I tried to change the font of bottom center button to the same font but only in bold it changed to what was in the runtime

Comment: @Slaw thanks for your help and for you trying to find the cause of the problem